# Space doesn't show on Minecraft Color Codes

Tags: javascript, minecraft

So I built this small JavaScript library on Github.
https://github.com/FoxInFlame/MinecraftColorCodes

Now, it works flawlessly. It translates Minecraft MOTDs into HTML codes, so that it can display it on websites.

I've implemented support for `\n`, where I use the replace function with RegEX to turn it into a `<br>`.

Now, I tested this library on the MOTD of a server called Mineplex.
Mineplex has it's MOTD centered, which means it has many spaces on either side, allowing it to stay in the center.

When I used my library, the spaces did not show up.
Here is a Fiddle of what I mean. The Top row is supposed to be centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/rm7t318u/1/

How can I solve this?

Comment: mmm? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

## I. Replace LEADING spaces

... with non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`).

```
var yourMOTD = "              §4§l§m  §f§l§m §8§l§m[ §r §4§lMineplex§r §f§lGames§r §8§l§m ]§f§l§m §4§l§m  §r\n  §2§l§n     M O N S T E R   M A Z E   B E T A     §f";

function normalizeIndent(str) {
    var boundry = /[^\s]/i.exec(str).index;
    return str.substr(0, boundry).replace(/[ ]/g, '&nbsp;') + str.substr(boundry);
}

replaceColorCodes(normalizeIndent(yourMOTD), "output");
```

## II. Apply CSS rule

... to your `.output` `<div>` to preserve spaces.

```css
.output {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Option 1, did not output correctly, and Option 2 did. So Option 2 it is!

Comment: @pokekart2002: Well, I tested both... :( Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/rm7t318u/3/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do not see the spaces is because in HTML, you can never see more than one space. To see more than one grouped spaces, we need to change the normal space to a special one, `&nbsp;`.

I have updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rm7t318u/2/

Comment: You could also preserve spaces by applying the following CSS rule: `.output { white-space: pre; }`.

Comment: You're right, that'd actually be better! Forgot about it, wrote too fast.

Comment: mmm! I think I'll go with @Mr.Polywhirl s. Can you make an answer based on the comment, so I can mark as correct?